# Help with Cantonese correct translation

Tags: translation, cantonese

I thouhgt about posting here twice as I know rules do not allow for users to simply ask for translations. But after a few efforst in trying to translate it myself, I decided to ask for your kind help.
The phrase that i would like to translate is here below. Does it mean "I am generous. Kim."? Or is there anything I am missing out?

睇下我嘅. Kim

Thank you.

Comment: I don't speak Cantonese, but that looks like "Look at my Kim". Doesn't make sense to me, unfortunately. If there's supposed to be a full stop after 嘅, then it just means....."Look at mine. Kim".

Comment: The full sentence is:

"C xc. X. Kl睇下我嘅 LKmi. Kim"

I mean, I really tried hard to understand what it means but I'm having a hard time with this.

Comment: it’s roughly “look at my [something?], kim”. in scenario like: kim & her friend are shopping for earrings, when kim is picking up one, her friend says “睇下我嘅. Kim”; in order to catch kim’s attention, to what does she choose.

Comment: Native Cantonese would put Kim at the beginning of the sentence and say: "Kim, 睇下我嘅 (usually there would be an object after 嘅); I suspect it is a 竹昇 Chinese ( second generation Chinese immigrant who are more western  than Chinese inside)

Answer (score 1):

"睇下我嘅"  (Taei har ngo gea)

"take a look at mine"

It is definitely colloquial Cantonese.

These kinds of "rough" phrases are usually meant to indicate something to boast or show off or a demeaning comparison, like, "pay attention, you might learn something"; "this is how I would do it"; "you see those biceps?"

This phrase therefore has to be a follow-on to demean someone else's poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

睇下我嘅 means "look at mine." or "look at my (something)." depends on what they're doing. 
睇 means "look" .  下is a empty word. 我means me or I. 我嘅 means my or mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the sentence in a wider context in order to find out what it really means because, as typical with any (if not all) Chinese words, they are context sensitive and will mean very different things in different situations.

I'm certain that it does NOT mean "I am generous. Kim."

"睇" formally means "look, watch". Therefore, "睇戲" means watch a movie. But in its colloquial and everyday usage, "睇" often means looking after, protecting or taking care of. Therefore, "睇下我" means "take care of me" or "do me a favor". Perhaps, someone was asking for Kim's protection?

Answer (score 0):

C xc. X. Kl睇下我嘅 LKmi. Kim
does not make sense to any Cantonese speaker.

C xc. X. Kl can hardly be understood, LKmi could be some kinda model number?
I suspect there could be some typo, but the full sentence could mean
1 [some unknown meaning], look at my something, Kim.
2 [some unknown meaning], (I) need to check my something, Kim.

Answer (score 0):

「睇下」means 'take a look'
「我嘅」means 'my (thing)'
Kim is most probably a person's name. So I presume Kim is the one leaving the note.

The whole sentence means "Take a look at mine!" Kim is probably trying to show you something. (If that note is for you.)
No, it doesn't mean 'I am generous.'

Answer (score -3):

I am a Chinese, but I don't know "睇下我嘅" means. It is not Chinese as I know. So you may want to get the correct Chinese sentence.